# issue creating a delay each time a react component is render from a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react component that is meant to render a sub component with a small delay between each time the sub component is called. This delay will changed what is rendered with the delay. I cant seem to figure out how to get that delay to work with each iteration I make inside the map fuction that is applied to an array. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ImageListItem from "./imageListItem"
import styles from "../../css/carousel/imageList.css"

export default function Option (props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <div style={styles.ImageList}>
        <div style={styles.ImageTemplate}>
          <button style={styles.ImageTempalateButton}>
            <img style={styles.ImageTemplateImage} src="" alt=""/>
          </button>
        </div>
        {
          props.images.map((image) => (
            <div key={image._id}>
              <ImageListItem currImage={image} waitBeforeShow={2000}/>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want the delay every time the ImageListItem is called. How can i do that with react?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer inside `ImageListItem` and [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) only after the timer has finished.

Some notes:

- Don't forget to clean up when the component is unmounted.
- If you want the items to render one after the other then the delay
  should get incremented for each child. this can be done with the
  `(index + 1) * deleyMs`

Here is a small proof of concept:

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

class Item extends React.Component {
  state = { shouldRender: false }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { deleyMs } = this.props;
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ shouldRender: true });
    }, deleyMs);
  }

  componentWillUnMount(){
    // cleanup
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }

  render() {
    const { text } = this.props;
    const { shouldRender } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {shouldRender && text}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        items.map((item, i) => <Item key={item} text={item} deleyMs={(i + 1) * 2000} />)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```